# What is the rule for using ‘a’ (to) to introduce someone?

Tags: gramática

In Spanish, what is the rule for using `a`  to introduce someone?

In Spanish, `a` means `to`, but it also [functions as a personal 'marker' before talking about another person](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/a).

In my textbook it has the following:

```
1)    Te presento a Sandra./ Let me introduce you to Sandra.
2)    Te presento a mi amigo Joaquín. / Let me introduce you to my friend Joaquín.
3)    Le presento mi familia. / Let me introduce you to my family.
```

Why does the last example not use `a` to introduce the family?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your textbook might be incorrect. Also, be aware that translating Sp. *a* to Eng. *to* might be misleading in this case.

The last example should use *a* just like the first and second. Employing *a* before the object is compulsory in a number of cases, most commonly when it's a person's proper name, but also when the object is

- the proper name of an animal;
- a collective noun that refers to a well-determined group of people;
- a common noun that refers to a concrete individual;
- a common noun, even if general, where the meaning of the verb includes physical or psychical affect;

and many others (sources: [Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=ctMgM8Bp2D6ELPuNfg)). So for example:

> *Dejé a Fido atado a un árbol.* ("I left Fido tied to a tree.")
>   *Echamos a toda la gente afuera.* ("We sent all the people outside.")
>   *Fui a ver al doctor.* ("I went to see the doctor.")
>   *Dicen que golpeó a una anciana.* ("They say he hit an old lady.")

Regarding which verbs always require *a* before the object, you have no alternative but to learn them by heart.

*Le presento mi familia*, just like that, sounds really odd to me. It would work if there was another explicit object in the sentence (which would be the referent of *le*):

> *Le presenté mi familia a mi amiga extranjera.*
>   "I introduced my family to my friend from abroad."

Things can get a bit muddled because of the particular semantics of *presentar* (which is somewhat weird because it has two objects but it works more or less the same if you exchange their place, since you cannot introduce A to B without introducing B to A). But in any case you have to use *a* with it.

Comment: `Regarding which verbs always require a before the object, you have no alternative but to learn them by heart.` Is there a list of these verbs (ideally with English translations?) thanks!

Comment: Also, would the correct sentence be `Le presento a mi familia.` with the `a` before `mi`? Thanks!

Comment: @big_smile To your first question: the [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=ctMgM8Bp2D6ELPuNfg) says *acompañar, admirar, afectar, alabar, amar, empujar, engañar, golpear, maltratar, matar, odiar, perjudicar, saludar* but there are others; I didn't mean that you had to memorize a list, but that you would learn the correct usage together with the verb, in the same way you have to learn the genders of nouns, by repetition.

Comment: @big_smile To your second: yes, *Le presento a mi familia* is the correct form.